Proving that $\Bbb Z$ is, up to isomorphism, the smallest domain into which we can embed $\Bbb N$
This question is ultimately motivated by this one (I am studying from the same book), but I feel like there is much more to be said and so I am hoping to ask a new one.
I've given the whole theorem below but want to emphasize that I am only interested in the uniqueness claim here. Asides in square brackets [] are given by me.

9.1 Theorem There is a smallest[in the sense that $\Bbb Z$ embeds into any other ] [integral] domain (commutative ring without zero divisors) with unity, $\Bbb Z$, such that $\Bbb N \subset \Bbb Z$ [in the sense of there existing an isomorphic embedding $E_\Bbb Z: \Bbb N \to \Bbb Z$], and the ring operations on $\Bbb Z$ restrict to the usual operations on $\Bbb N$. This ring is unique up to isomorphism and is called the ring of integers.

Now lots is to be proved in the theorem above, so I want to emphasize again that with this question I am only interested in the last sentence:

This ring is unique up to isomorphism and is called the ring of integers. [More precisely, we claim that $R$ and $\Bbb Z$ are isomorphic for any domain $R$ into which $\Bbb N$ embeds, and for which $R$ embeds into $S$ for any other domain $S$ into which $\Bbb N$ embeds.]

I am hoping to summarize a proof strategy: is the following correct?
My proof strategy:
Let us say that a domain $S$ is smallest (in our present context) if $\Bbb N$ embeds into $S$ with $E_S$ and if, for any other domain $R$ such that $E_R: \mathbb{N}\to R$ is some embeddings of the naturals, then a unique embedding $F_{S,R}: S\to R$ is induced which (*, this will be used later) restricts to that of $E_R: \mathbb{N}\to R$ (that is, for all $n \in \Bbb N$, $F_{S,R} \mid_{E_S(\mathbb{N})}(E_S(n)) = E_R(n)$).
(1) Show that $\Bbb Z$ is a smallest domain.
Proof.  Omitted.
(2) Suppose that $S$ is a smallest domain. Then $\Bbb Z \cong S$.
Proof.  We have by hypothesis and (1) that there exist unique embeddings $F_{S,\Bbb Z}, F_{\Bbb Z,S}$. Since both embeddings are (by part of the definition of embedding) injective, it is sufficient to verify that  $F_{S,\Bbb Z} \circ F_{\Bbb Z,S} = I_\Bbb Z$ in order to show that $F_{\Bbb Z,S}$ has an inverse (and is thus bijective, and so an isomorphism since it's already a homomorphism). Thus we let $a \in \Bbb Z$ and note that by definition of $a$ there exist naturals $m,n$ such that $a = [(m,n)]$. By basic properties in $\Bbb Z$ we have
$$a = [(m,n)] = [(m,0)] + [(0,n)] = [(m,0)] + (-[(n,0)]) = E_\Bbb Z (m) - E_\Bbb Z (n).$$
Then, calculating, we find that
$$F_{S,\Bbb Z} \circ F_{\Bbb Z,S}(a) = F_{S,\Bbb Z}(F_{\Bbb Z,S}(a)) = F_{S,\Bbb Z}(F_{\Bbb Z,S}(E_\Bbb Z (m) - E_\Bbb Z (n))) = F_{S,\Bbb Z}(F_{\Bbb Z,S}(E_\Bbb Z (m)) - F_{\Bbb Z,S}(E_\Bbb Z (n))) \stackrel{(1)}{=} F_{S,\Bbb Z}(E_S(m) - E_S(n)) \stackrel{(1)}{=} E_\Bbb Z (m) - E_\Bbb Z (n) = a,$$
where we have made various uses of the homomorphism properties of the $F_i$ and where in the crucial steps marked (1) we have used the property (*) above.
My questions:
(1) Does my proof (strategy) appear correct?
(2) In my definition of smallest above (developed after a discussion with others), I mention that "then a unique embedding $F_{S,R}: S\to R$ is induced". Where is this hypothesis about the embedding being unique used or needed (not a question about whether it's true or not)? As far as I can tell, all we need is the property (*) which the embedding has.

You are right, it is not needed. But interestingly, uniqueness is not needed in the definition of smallest, it follows from the other axioms.
Let's assume $S$ is such a smallest set, except we don't assume uniqueness of the homomorphisms. Let $R$ and $F_{S,R}$ be given as you write them, and let $G_{S,R}$ be another homomorphism from $S$ to $R$ satisying the same conditions. Almost by definition, the homomorphisms agree on $E_S(\mathbb{N})$, and since they are homomorphisms, the agree on zero.
To prove they agree on the rest of $S$, we will use the following decomposition:
$S=E_S(\mathbb{N}) \cup \{0\}\cup (-E_S(\mathbb{N}))$
where $-E_S(\mathbb{N})=\{-s| s\in E_S(\mathbb{N})\}$. This follows pretty much from the fact that $S$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.
Now we're good to go. Let $s\in S$. If $s\in E_S(\mathbb{N}) \cup \{0\}$, we already konw the homomoprhisms agree. So assume $s\in -E_S(\mathbb{N})$. Again using the isomorphism from $S$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, we see that $-s\in E_S(\mathbb{N})$. Therefore we have that
$F_{S,R}(s)=-F_{S,R}(-s)=-G_{S,R}(-s)=G_{S,R}(s)$
where the middle equality follows since $-s\in E_S(\mathbb{N})$. So we have checked all cases, and conclude that $F_{S,R}=G_{S,R}$, so the homomorphism is unique.
I left out some details, let me know if something is not clear.

Thanks so much for your answer! Would it be possible to expand on the two instances in which you say we use that $\Bbb Z \cong S$? I am not sure I see what you are doing there. Also, is this necessary to do? I would have thought that (as you say) the fact that we can omit "unique" from the definition of smallest would follow without reference to $\Bbb Z$ as a "middleman", right?

It is absolutely not necessary no :). The use of the isomophism to $\mathbb{Z}$ is a really good point, I just did it for convenience. I will think about it, and get back to you!
